# Convert the result of LINQ query to list of Custom Model

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, linq, model-view-controller

Good evening everyone.

I have a LINQ to SQL query result, and I want to convert this result to a list of Custom Model class

down here the Class Model:

```
public class Beneficiary
    {
        public int BeneficiaryId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public DateTime? CreatedAt { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "date")]
        public DateTime? BithDate { get; set; }

        public int? CommunityId { get; set; }
        public virtual Community Community { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Gender { get; set; }


        public string IdNumber { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string AppName { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        public string BeneficiaryNumber { get; set; }

        public int CompanyId { get; set; }
        public virtual Company Company { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<BeneficiaryProject> BeneficiaryProjects { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Card> Cards { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Invoice> Invoices { get; set; }
    }
```

and here is the query that I used :

```
var list  = (from B in db.Beneficiaries
                               join ben in db.BeneficiaryProjects on B.BeneficiaryId equals ben.BeneficiaryId
                               where (ben.CardNeeded == true && ben.ProjectId == temp.ProjectId)
                               select new Beneficiary()
                               {
                                   BeneficiaryId = B.BeneficiaryId,
                                   FirstName = B.FirstName,
                                   LastName = B.LastName,
                                   IdNumber = B.IdNumber,
                                   Gender = B.Gender
                               });
```

the above query is successfully executed, but when I convert the `var list` to a list of `Beneficiary` as following:

```
            List<Beneficiary> list1 = list.ToList<Beneficiary>();
```

but I got the below exception :

```
 An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The entity or complex type 'E_Voucher.Models.Beneficiary' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.
```

Comment: Have you tried this: `List<Beneficiary> BeneficiaryList = (your query here).ToList();`

Comment: Note that the query itself is not executed until you call `ToList`, so you may _think_ it executes successfully, but in fact it does not.

Comment: Looking over your query, there may be an issue with temp.ProjectID. are you missing a join?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you are getting this error 
(in this line:)

```
List<Beneficiary> list1 = list.ToList<Beneficiary>();
```

is that you are trying to convert a Linq Query variable to a List.

All you really need to do is the following:

```
List<Beneficiary> list1 = list.ToList();
```

the query you have for temp.ProjectID:

```
var projects = db.Projects.Where(p => p.ContractId == id); foreach (var temp in projects)
```

should be something like:

```
int ProjectId = (from P in db.Projects where P.ContractId == id select P.ProjectId).FirstOrDefault();
```

and then take that value and put into your next query:

```
... where (ben.CardNeeded == true && ben.ProjectId == ProjectId)
```

Comment: Looking over your original query, there may be an issue with temp.ProjectID. are you missing a join?

Comment: where are you mean I missed a join ?

Comment: what  is temp.ProjectId , or where is it coming from? Is it a temp Table?

Comment: I get the projectId as following var projects = db.Projects.Where(p => p.ContractId == id); foreach (var temp in projects) { // code of the question here } , is this true ?? where `id` is a input to a function

Comment: That is your issue! 
you need to convert the query (for projectId) query into a queryable object or just get that value before you include in your main query.

Comment: @yes you are right! when I tried to put a fixed value (like 3 instead of `temp.ProjectId`) it worked!!, how to make it works using the `temp.ProjectId` ?

Comment: I modified my answer with the query for ProjectID.
Please let me know if you need any more info

Comment: thank you very much for your time, the query is executed without any exception ! thank you again :)

Answer (score 3):

Make conversion to custom class after retrieving the results from EF:

```
var list  = (
    from B in db.Beneficiaries
    join ben in db.BeneficiaryProjects on B.BeneficiaryId equals ben.BeneficiaryId
    where (ben.CardNeeded == true && ben.ProjectId == temp.ProjectId)
    select new {
        B.BeneficiaryId,
        B.FirstName,
        B.LastName,
        B.IdNumber,
        B.Gender
    }
).AsEnumerable()
.Select(B => new Beneficiary() {
    BeneficiaryId = B.BeneficiaryId,
    FirstName = B.FirstName,
    LastName = B.LastName,
    IdNumber = B.IdNumber,
    Gender = B.Gender
}).ToList();
```

**Note:** The reason you get the error on running `ToList` is that EF queries *defer* execution. Your query may be incorrect, but the only way to find out is to try getting its results.

Comment: Thanks, I tried your query, but I still get the following exception `An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.`

Comment: @MGCR7 That's very odd. I edited the answer, could you give the updated one a try?

Comment: This is probably due to trying to enumerate (AsEnumerable()).
you should try my suggested solution with your original query.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight still get the same exception I typed above in my comment

Comment: @MGCR7 I think at this point the error is no longer related to type conversion. Are you sure you are running this against a correct DB?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight yes, it's a local database and it's running with other queries

Comment: @MGCR7 Could you try `foreach(var x in (from B in db.Beneficiaries
    join ben in db.BeneficiaryProjects on B.BeneficiaryId equals ben.BeneficiaryId
    where (ben.CardNeeded == true && ben.ProjectId == temp.ProjectId))) {Console.WriteLine(B.BeneficiaryId);}` loop, and see if you get the same exception?

Comment: when you say "other queries" do you mean that you are querying the temp.ProjectId from a temporary table ?

Comment: @DaniDev I get the projectId as following `var projects = db.Projects.Where(p => p.ContractId == id);
            foreach (var temp in projects)
            {
// code of the question here
}` , is this true ??

Comment: @MGCR7 Deferred execution may "get" you again - try adding `ToList()`, i.e. `foreach (var temp in projects.ToList())`

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I tried `project.ToList()` but also same exception

Comment: @dasblinkenlight thanks for your query, it was very helpful.. thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can't project your object of type Beneficiary from within LINQ to Entities to a mapped entity object.

Try this:

```
db.Beneficiaries.Join(db.BeneficiaryProjects, B => B.BeneficiaryId, ben => ben.BeneficiaryId, (B, ben) => new { B, ben })
                .Where(x => x.ben.CardNeeded == true && x.ben.ProjectId == temp.ProjectId)
                .Select(x => x.B)
                .ToList();
```

It's a lamda expression that should do the same thing as your LINQ query but will select your Beneficiary model object and map it. The `ToList()` can be replaced with an `AsQueryable()` or `AsEnumerable()` based on your need.

Comment: thanks, I tried your suggestion, but I got the following exception 'An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code'

Comment: @MGCR7 When you hit the exception, check the inner exception.. that should give you more insight into the exact issue.